# How can I sum the value of a customfiled when posts have the same date?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to make a calendar for my wordpress site and I have a code that shows fine.

I run into the fact that I want to add a custom field to posts with the same date. All the loops in my current code make it too complex for me.

I've already tried a lot and thought I was close to it every now and then, but now I'm stuck.
Can someone help me further?

```
<?php
$year = date('Y');
$custom_field_key = 'opbrengst'; // Replace with the key of the custom field you want to get the value from
$monthNames = array(
    1 => 'Januari',
    2 => 'Februari',
    3 => 'Maart',
    4 => 'April',
    5 => 'Mei',
    6 => 'Juni',
    7 => 'Juli',
    8 => 'Augustus',
    9 => 'September',
    10 => 'Oktober',
    11 => 'November',
    12 => 'December'
);

for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
    $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $monthName = $monthNames[$month];
    echo "<div class='month'>";
    echo "<table class='calendar table-flex'>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan='7'>$monthName</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Ma</td><td>Di</td><td>Wo</td><td>Do</td><td>Vr</td><td>Za</td><td>Zo</td></tr>";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++) {
        $dayOfWeek = date('N', strtotime("$year-$month-$i"));
        if ($i == 1) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = 1; $j < $dayOfWeek; $j++) {
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
        }
        $date = "$year-$month-$i";
        $args = array(
            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'year' => $year,
                    'month' => $month,
                    'day' => $i,
                ),
            ),
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($query->have_posts()) {
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();
                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $custom_field_key, true);
                // set background color
                $custom_field_value > 0 ? $color = "green" : $color = "red";

                if ($dayOfWeek == 7) {
                    echo "<td class=\"$color\">$i<br>$ $custom_field_value</td></tr><tr>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td class=\"$color\">$i<br>$ $custom_field_value</td>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($dayOfWeek == 7) {
                echo "<td>$i</td></tr><tr>";
            } else {
                echo "<td>$i</td>";
            }
        }
    }

    echo "</tr></table>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

This is a working example as I want it to integrate it in my calendar.

```
<?php
$custom_field_key = 'opbrengst';

$startDatum = "2023-01-01";
$eindDatum = "2023-12-30";

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'datum',
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'value' => array($startDatum, $eindDatum),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        ),
    )
);


$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$sum = 0;
$prev_date = '';
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $date = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' );
        if ( $prev_date == '' || $prev_date != $date ) {
            if ( $prev_date != '' ) {
                echo '<p>Sum of custom field for date '.$prev_date.': '.$sum.'</p>';
            }
            $sum = 0;
            $prev_date = $date;
        }
        $sum += get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $custom_field_key, true );
    }
    echo '<p>Sum of custom field for date '.$prev_date.': '.$sum.'</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```